# Ignite Local Entries and Spilled to Disk Entries

Tags: ignite

For apache Ignite, when a key-value cache is spilled to disk is it spilled a key at a time or will it spill part of the value to disk?

In addition, for IgniteCache.localentries() will that automatically read all the values from disk or is there a way to traverse the in-memory ones first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eviction happens on per-entry basis. E.g., you can't remove only half of the value from memory.

As for `localEntries` method, its behavior depends on provided `CachePeekMode`(s). For example, to get entries from all storage layers, call it like this:

```
cache.localEntries(CachePeekMode.ALL);
```

Comment: So for in memory it would be OffHeap and OnHead depending on the cache configuration?  And Swap for the ones spilled to disk?

Comment: Yes, there are separate modes for different storage tiers. `ALL` combines everything in one.

Comment: Cool. I was partially adding to confirm, and partially to round out the answer.  :-D  Thanks!